# How to send Ajax call to an INPUT value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

My knowledge about javascript is very low; thus, this is a simple question. I have a simple jQuery Ajax function as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#txtValue').keyup(function(event){
      if(event.which == 13){
            sendValue($(this).val());   
      }
   }); 
});

function sendValue(str){
    $.post("test.php",{ sendValue: str },
    function(data){
        $('#display').html(data.returnValue);
    }, "json");
}
```

This sends the json response to  with id="display"

```
<input type="text" name="txtValue" value="" id="txtValue">
<div id="display"></div>
```

But instead I want to put the json response as value of another INPUT element in a different form as

```
<form method="get" action="result.php">
<input id="DISPLAY" type="text" name="something" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I want to put json response to  and  instead of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put return value to input, you need to use `.val(data.returnValue)` instead of `.html(data.returnValue)`

Comment: I wish I could give +10 for such a concise and definite answer. It works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

if the form is on the same page :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#txtValue').keyup(function(event){
      if(event.which == 13){
         sendValue($(this).val());   
      }
    }); 
});

function sendValue(str){
   $.post("test.php",{ sendValue: str },
   function(data){
       $(':input#DISPLAY').html(data.returnValue);
   }, "json");
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but this does not work for <INPUT> with id="display". The CAPITAL was only here to emphasize my request.

Comment: the form is on the same page ?

Comment: Yes, it is. The problem is that it sends to <div id="display"></div> but not to <input type="text" name="new" value="" id="display" />

Comment: wjy the hell do you have the same id in the Document ?

Comment: No I do not have two elements with the same ID. I use only one of them. When I use <div>, it works; but when I use <input> it does not work. I said my knowledge about javascript is low but not nothing :D

Comment: @Ali with div it works because you are using `html` when you want to set the `value` of an input element you use `.val()` in jquery because the input element has no property as `html`

Answer (score 1):

use `.val()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#txtValue').keyup(function(event){
     if(event.which == 13){
        sendValue($(this).val());   
     }
  }); 
});
function sendValue(str){
  $.post("test.php",{ sendValue: str },
  function(data){
     $("#display").val(data.returnValue);           
  }, "json");
}
```

Comment: This will create (add) a new INPUT field upon receiving json data, instead of putting the data within the current INPUT field.